# Restricted pointer assignments

Tags: c, pointers, alias, c99, restrict-qualifier

I have a question regarding restricted pointer assignments.  See the comments in code for specific questions.  Overall, I'm just wondering what's legal with restrict (I've read the standard, but still have questions :-(

```
int* Q = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);

{
    int* restrict R = Q;

    for(int j = 0; j < rand()%50; j++)
    {
        R[j] = rand();
    }

    Q = R; // The standard says assigning restricted child pointers to their parent is illegal.
           // If Q was a restricted pointer, is it correct to assume that this would be ILLEGAL?
           //
           // Since Q is unrestricted, is this a legal assignment?
           //
           // I guess I'm just wondering: 
           // What's the appropriate way to carry the value of R out of the block so
           // the code can continue where the above loop left off? 
}

{
    int* S = Q;   // unrestricted child pointers, continuing where R left off above
    int* T = Q+1; // S and T alias with these assignments

    for(int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
    {
        S[j] = T[j];
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by “carry the value of `R` out of the block”? Your code doesn't modify `R` at all, you have `R == Q` at all places where `R` is in scope. BTW, accepting an answer mere minutes after you've posed a question is something long-term users recommend against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the object being modified (the array allocated in first line) isn't modified through an lvalue expression except involving the restricted pointer, `R` in that block where `R` is declared, I think that the code in your example is well-defined.

If `Q` were a restricted pointer, the example would be undefined.

Comment: You're welcome - just realize that I find the wording of the `restrict` definition to be quite difficult to follow (probably as you do, too), so my confidence in my answer might not be as strong as for other answers...